# column headers misaligned with data in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

[image]I am new to the `webDevelopment` and `angular`. I have added the table header fix thing. But because of this, headers misaligned with the data in the table.

```css
.tableBodyScroll tbody {
    display:block;
    max-height:300px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    }
    .tableBodyScroll thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 nopadding tableBodyScroll">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
                <thead class="text-center text-info text-capitalize">
                    <th class="text-center">Sr.No.</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Document</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Score</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="file in processResumeFiles">
                        <td class="text-center">{{ file.id }}</td>
                        <td class="view-orphan uploadResumeTableCellOverFlow">
                            {{ file.attributes.name }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{file.totalScore}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to see" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isUploadedDocument" data-ng-click="somemethod($index)">
                                <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to move" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isCommitted || !file.attributes.isUploadedDocument" data-ng-click="somemethod(file.attributes.name)">
                                <i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to delete " data-ng-click="deleteResume(file.attributes.name)">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to Move " ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isCommitted || !file.attributes.isUploadedDocument" data-ng-click="somemethod(file.attributes.name)">
                                <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="Click to move " ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isCommitted || !isjdDeleted || !jdSelected" data-ng-click="moveToJobDescription(file.attributes.name)">
                                <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So, now here I am using this `tableBodyScroll` then it is fixing the header as well as adding the scroll bar but giving that error. 
Can any one help me with this? Buttons are also not in  the one line. can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use table with titles like this :

```html
<table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
            {{user.name}}</td>
        <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
            {{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No, This is not creating the problem

Answer (score 0):

From what i can understand. Your "text-center" class is not being applied correctly to the data in . I have added text-center class to your css. The data is aligned now.

```css
.tableBodyScroll tbody {
    display:block;
    max-height:300px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    }
    .tableBodyScroll thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    }
    .text-center {
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 nopadding tableBodyScroll">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
                <thead class="text-center text-info text-capitalize">
                    <th class="text-center">Sr.No.</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Document</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Score</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="file in processResumeFiles">
                        <td class="text-center">{{ file.id }}</td>
                        <td class="view-orphan uploadResumeTableCellOverFlow">
                            {{ file.attributes.name }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{file.totalScore}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to see" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isUploadedDocument" data-ng-click="somemethod($index)">
                                <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to move" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isCommitted || !file.attributes.isUploadedDocument" data-ng-click="somemethod(file.attributes.name)">
                                <i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to delete " data-ng-click="deleteResume(file.attributes.name)">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to Move " ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isCommitted || !file.attributes.isUploadedDocument" data-ng-click="somemethod(file.attributes.name)">
                                <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="Click to move " ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isCommitted || !isjdDeleted || !jdSelected" data-ng-click="moveToJobDescription(file.attributes.name)">
                                <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry but no change still same